# run nosetests in all subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I can run tests in `workflow` folder with `nosetests`:

```
workflow maks$ nosetests
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.093s

OK
```

my tests live in `test` folder:

```
workflow maks$ ls
__pycache__     iterations.py       test
data            iterationsClass.py  testData
env         iterationsClass.pyc
```

But when I move to parent dir:

```
(py3env)Makss-Mac:workflow maks$ cd ..
```

It cannot find tests.

```
(py3env)Makss-Mac:Packages maks$ nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.005s

OK
```

So how to make nosetest search tests in all subdirectories?

Answer (score 18):

If you make your `workflow` folder a module by placing `__init__.py` in it, nose should be able to find your tests.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to make your folder a module, put a `setup.cfg` in the directory you want to run `nosetests` which automatically passes the `tests` option to `nosetests` to specify relative location of tests. Like so:

```
#setup.cfg contents:

[nosetests]
exe = True
tests = workflow/
```

You can also pass multiple folders/tests using this same mechanism:

```
#setup.cfg contents:

[nosetests]
exe = True
tests = workflow/, other/dir/full/of/tests/, direct/file/my_test.py
```